# UVa #494 - regex [^a-zA-z]+ to split words using Java

Tags: java, regex, logic

I was playing with [UVa #494](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=435) and I managed to solve it with the code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            String words[] = line.split("[^a-zA-z]+");
            int cnt = words.length;
            // for some reason it is counting two words for 234234ddfdfd and words[0] is empty
            if(cnt != 0 && words[0].isEmpty()) cnt--; // ugly fix, if has words and the first is empty, reduce one word
            System.out.println(cnt);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I built the regex `"[^a-zA-z]+"` to split the words so for example the strings `abc..abc` or `abc432abc` should be splitted as `["abc", "abc"]`. However, when I try the string `432abc`, I have as a result `["", "abc"]` - the first element from `words[]` is just an empty string but I was expecting to have just `["abc"]`. I can't figure out why this regex gives me the first element as `""` for this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the split reference page: [split reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

> Each element of separator defines a separate delimiter character. If
>   two delimiters are adjacent, or a delimiter is found at the beginning
>   or end of this instance, the corresponding array element contains
>   Empty. The following table provides examples.

Since you have several consecutive delimiter characters, you get empty array elements

Answer (score 3):

Prints the count of number of words

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            int count = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
```